# Log in issue to StackExchnage

Tags: discussion, status-completed, editing

I have posted the following question a month ago and now I am trying to edit or comment on it, but it does not allow me to do so. It says I don't have 50 reputations, while in actual I have more than 50. Could someone figure it out, please?
"SciJewel" is my display name. Thanks!

[Problem with log-log list contour plot and filling its selective parts with contour shading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237009/problem-with-log-log-list-contour-plot-and-filling-its-selective-parts-with-cont)

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to regain access to your account.

Comment: They asked to fill a questionnaire and I did it.